# Зачем в библиотеках используются макросы вместо языковых конструкций?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, макросы

Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем в стандартной библиотеке, в библиотеках boost и во многих других библиотеках некоторые ключевые слова, названия пространств имен, функций и т.п. оформляются в виде макросов? Например, `_XSTD`, `NOEXCEPT`, `THROW`, `and` и еще многие другие. При этом имеются ввиду т.н. «рабочие» макросы, т.е. те, которые взаимодействуют с основным кодом на C++, а не что-то платформенное типа `_MSC_VER` или `__WIN__`. Хотелось бы услышать в **ответе** некоторые причины/варианты использования в библиотеках макросов.

Answer (score 5):

Что касается использования макросов вида `THROW`, `CATCH` и т.п., то такие вводятся для возможности отключить механизм исключений при необходимости (пустое определение).

Макросы вида `NOEXCEPT`, `DEFAULT` и т.п. вводятся с той целью, чтобы бибилотека могла работать с более старыми версиями компиляторов. Например, в boost имеется `config`-файл, в котором содержатся директивы `#define`, определяющие или не определяющие, например, `BOOST_HAS_CXX_RVALUE_REFERENCES` или `BOOST_HAS_NOEXCEPT` - это зависит от версии компилятора. Далее, `#ifndef`-ом определяется соответствующий макрос - либо вводя его как альтернативу, например, тому же `noexcept`, либо делая его «пустышкой».

Answer (score 3):

Мало ли как придется в новой версии объявлять функции?
Вдруг изменится какой-то тип?
Или, например, реальная ситуация - изменение спецификации исключений в новом стандарте. Или эти исключения просто нужно будет отключить? Или сейчас компилятор понимает `throw()`, но пока не понимает `noexcept`?

Словом, максимально обезопасить себя от будущих неприятностей - чтобы при необходимости внесения изменений внести их в минимальном объеме.

При этом еще и нужно сделать так, чтобы это работало и в C, и в C++.
Да еще и разрабатывалось это все лет 30 назад, а то и раньше.

Вот так и стали использоваться именно макросы - как наиболее отвязанное от языка и доступное в те времена, когда еще и C++ не было :) средство.

*"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

Comment: При этом еще и нужно сделать так, чтобы это работало и в C, и в C++. - а что это значит? Если пишем проект на C++, зачем нам вводить возможность работы под С-компилятором?

Comment: Harry, а как понять, нужно ли и что именно мне оборачивать такой макроконструкцией в своем коде? Я пишу его в надежде, что он будет компилироваться на новых компиляторах ;)

Comment: А, например, `windows.h` и иже с ним. Я по вопросу думал, что это кивок в первую очередь в их сторону. А вообще - все это предельно четко определяется корпоративными стандартами. Так что разрабатывайте свой стандарт и следуйте ему. Или попробуйте украсть у MS их вариант :)

Comment: Кстати, варианты стандартов кодирования для интереса: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml или вот - www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю. Гугловский документ, что-то не открывается (